# Select from a table and Insert new records into another table but change some values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

I have a 1 to many relationship between two tables... say Organisation and Members

I want to create a new Organisation based on an existing one (ID 111) and copy all the members but associate them with the newly created organisation.

some pseudo code..

```
-- Just create a new organisation based on the new name and address
-- passed to the proc.
Insert into Organisation (newOrganisationName, newAddress) 
returning Organisation_ID into v_orgID;
```

So now I have the new organisation id returned in  v_orgID of say 999 and I want to copy the members from an existing Organisation with say an ID of 111 and associate these with the new OrgID.

What is the best way to achieve this... should I loop and insert or can I use the Insert Into - select from method

```
INSERT INTO Members (OrganisationID, Membername, MemberAddress)
(SELECT  v_orgID, MemberName, MemberAddress FROM Member
 WHERE  OrganisationId = 111)
```

thanks Mick

Comment: Insert/select is the best way to do this, would be quicker,use less resource, and be simplier too.

Comment: Thanks Kevin... just did that and it worked a treat... just wasnt sure in substuiting the variables in but decided to suck it and see :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just insert the v_orgID into the query as a number:

```
INSERT INTO ... (SELECT 999, MemberName, MemberAddress FROM Member WHERE  OrganisationId = 111)
```

For 999 as the new OrganizationId.

Comment: Thanks Gents... all sorted now :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use INSERT/SELECT, changing the value:

```
INSERT INTO Members (OrganisationID, Membername, MemberAddress)
SELECT  999, MemberName, MemberAddress FROM Member
 WHERE  OrganisationId = 111
```

Comment: Sorry Gents but just to clarify... I didnt hard code the 999 as per your examples but used the variable substitution... as in 

    INSERT INTO Members (OrganisationID, Membername, MemberAddress) (SELECT v_orgID, MemberName, MemberAddress FROM Member WHERE OrganisationId = 111)

regards Mick